# Convergence in mean-square of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

I have a question concerning the convergence in mean square of a sequence of independent random variables: Let $\left(X_{n} \right)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of non-negative independent random variables satisfying $E{\left[X_{n} \right] } = 1/n^{2}$. Set $$ Y_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}  \quad \text{and} \quad Y = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}X_{k}.$$ By using the Monotone convergence theorem, one can easily show that 
$$ E{\left[ Y - Y_{n} \right] } = E {\left[\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}X_{k}\right]  } = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}E{\left[  X_{k}\right]} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2}}} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to +\infty.
$$ and, therefore, $Y_{n}$ converges to $Y$ in mean. Observe that we do not need the independence of the $X_{n}$'s in our agrument here.

Here is my question: Does $Y_{n}$ converge to $Y$ in mean square? (assume that the sequence $\left( X_{n} \right)$ is independent). I guess the answer is negative and I am trying to find an example to show that $Y$ does not belong to $L^{2}$ in general (my goal so far is to find a sequence such that the sum of variances of $X_{n}$ goes to $+\infty$). That's my attempt so far in figuring out this question.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try $X_n=0$ or $n^2$ with probabilities $1-\frac1{n^4}$ and $\frac1{n^4}$ respectively, then $E(X_n)=\frac1{n^2}$, as desired, hence $(Y_n)$ converges in $L^1$, and $E(X_n^2)=1$ does not converge to $0$ hence $(Y_n)$ does not converge in $L^2$.

Comment: Your example works perfectly! In this case, we can show that $E{\left[ Y -Y_{n} \right]}$ is indeed $+\infty$ for all $n$. That is what I was thinking of. Perfect example!

Comment: You might mean $E((Y-Y_n)^2)=+\infty$ instead of $E(Y-Y_n)=+\infty$, since $E(Y-Y_n)=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$ is finite for every $n$. Yes, $E((Y-Y_n)^2)=+\infty$ for every $n$.

Comment: That's correct. It was a typo in my previous comment. In this case we can show that $E{ \left[ \left( Y-Y_{n} \right)^{2}  \right]}$ is indeed $+\infty$ for all $n$. So we don't have the convergence in mean square.

Answer (score 0):

In this question, does $Y_n$ converge almost surely to $Y$?can we say $P(\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} X_i>\epsilon)<\dfrac{E(\sum(X_i)}{\epsilon}=\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^2}$ is 0 and then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p(\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty}> \epsilon)<\infty$ therefore$\ Y_n$ converges to $Y$ almost surely by Borel Cantelli Lemma?